# How to get Path in the form "file://///SERVER//folder1/folder2/

Tags: python, server, path

i am rather new to python and i have the following problem (just an example):

```
 import os
 mypath = 'I:\Folder1'
 for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(mypath):
        for f in filenames:
            getpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
```

returns the path in the form:

> I:\Folder1\Folder2

which is normally ok for me

However "I:\" is one of our servers at work and for further processing (html stuff) i would need the exact address in such a form

> file://///Servername/Subfolder/Folder1/Folder2

Edit: In other words:

My program may be used locally or on different servers - it just depends on the user.  Rather stupidly said I need a function that returns what in win10 goes like this: "right click on a folder --> Path Copy --> file:////....". And I only know that this path on my computer is called "I:\Folder1" ..but "I:\Folder1" is the server name

Edit 2: Solved (see comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a Windows platform and need forward slashes, it is actually possible to import the OS specific version. For example you could use [`posixpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=normpath#module-os.path).

To solve your problem you would need to first strip off `mypath` from each return `dirpath`. Next split this into folder components using split with your operating system's seperator i.e. `\`. This can then be all rejoined with a `server` prefix using the `posixpath.join()` command. For example:

```
import posixpath
import os

mypath = r'I:\Folder1'
server = 'file://///Servername/Subfolder'

for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(mypath):
    for f in filenames:
        subfolder = dirpath[len(mypath):]
        server_path = posixpath.join(server, *subfolder.split(os.sep), f)
        print(server_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe i didnt describe it perfectly. Your solution works if i know what the server name is - so as a workaround i did it more or less exactly like that. However my program may be used locally or on different servers - it just depends on the user. (its about extracting images from files)

Comment: So you are also looking for a way to get a servername from `I:\\` ?

Comment: Take a look at `win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(r'I:\', 1)`. You would need `import win32wnet`